# save download image in raw folder

Tags: android, image

I want to save a download image into raw folder. I tried below code for downloading image

```
public class Image extends FilterInputStream {
    public Image(InputStream in) {
      super(in);
    }
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
      long m = 0L;
      while (m < n) {
        long _m = in.skip(n-m);
        if (_m == 0L) break;
        m += _m;
      }

      return m;
    }
}
```

The above code is working for downloading the image, so I want to save that download in raw folder. Please tell me the process.

Comment: Did you save the image in any other folder?

Comment: http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/2012/02/download-store-and-read-images-from.html Above code can help you to easily download and display images from URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify the resources folders at runtime and raw is one of them. Store the file to any other location: internal memory or external memory. Or even to the db.